# My media screen not working in display:grid

Tags: css

My original code has 3 columns an 2 rows.
I want it to show 2 columns and 3 rows in the small screen.
But it not working.

```
.little_news {
display: grid;
margin:1em;
grid-template-columns: 10px 10px 10px;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 320px;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
justify-items: center;
align-content: center;
```

}

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {.little_news {
display: grid;
margin: 1em;
grid-template-columns: 10px 10px;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 320px;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
justify-items: center;
align-content: center;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the media query for 1200px, you have only specified 2 rows

To specify 3 rows try

`grid-template-rows : 100px 100px 100px;`

Comment: I changed to 3 rows but still not working

Comment: setting these properties on the parent element only will not give the expected behaviour(explained in the question) make sure you have correct number of child elements and also you must add `grid-rows` and `grid-columns` property to all child elements.

Comment: if this doesn't solve the problem  try to providing the entire code to debug better